# How can import this JSON with nested objects to Excel using Power Query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, json

I need to import a JSON file into Excel in table format. The JSON file has nested objects that I need to display as the column data. I've watched several videos, read the docs and forums and cannot figure this out - total mental block.

Here's the JSON (only two records ("rows"))

```
[{
        "records": [{
                "value": "C000087",
                "metadata": {
                    "colName": "CustID"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "421444",
                "metadata": {
                    "colName": "JobNumber"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": 3.1367982079090906,
                "metadata": {
                    "colName": "TotalSalesTax"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "records": [{
                "value": "C000087",
                "metadata": {
                    "colName": "CustID"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": "421447",
                "metadata": {
                    "colName": "JobNumber"
                }
            },
            {
                "value": 68.0271851016993,
                "metadata": {
                    "colName": "TotalSalesTax"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In Excel I'm using Data > Get Data > From File, the preview loads and I click Convert to Table and then have this:

[image]

It's showing my two records as rows (good) but only the one column for the top level object. I need to have 3 columns with these paths into the JSON:

```
Column Name: records[0].metadata.colName, Value: records[0].value
Column Name: records[1].metadata.colName, Value: records[1].value
Column Name: records[2].metadata.colName, Value: records[2].value
```

Or this:

| CustID | JobNumber | TotalSalesTax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C000087 | 421444 | 3.1367982079090906 |
| C000087 | 421447 | 68.0271851016993 |

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

- Expand the lists of records to new rows to create a table with one column of column names, and the other of values
- Pivot the column names with no aggregation using a custom function

*Please explore the applied steps to better understand the algorithm.*

***Custom Function***
*rename `fnPivotAll`*

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

//Rename:  fnPivotAll 

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

***Main Code***

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\json.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"records"}, {"records"}),
    #"Expanded records" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "records"),
    #"Expanded records1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded records", "records", {"value", "metadata"}, {"value", "metadata"}),
    #"Expanded metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded records1", "metadata", {"colName"}, {"colName"}),
    pivot = fnPivotAll(#"Expanded metadata","colName", "value"),

//set data types however you want
//I lazily set them all to text, but you could use text / number / percent
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(pivot, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(pivot), each {_, type text}))
in
    typeIt
```

***Results***
[image]